# How to convert FileOpenDialog's return value into array in autoit?

Tags: autoit

This is the code :-

```
Local $var = FileOpenDialog($message, @WindowsDir & "\", "Images (*.jpg;*.bmp)", 1 + 4)

If @error Then
    MsgBox(4096, "", "No File(s) chosen")
Else
    $var = StringReplace($var, "|", @CRLF)
    MsgBox(4096, "", "You chose " & $var)
EndIf
```

`FileOpenDialog` returns string and I just want it to convert to an array which stores the names of image files. I used `StringToASCIIArray`, but it returned some junk values which were not file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine. If my understanding is correct and all you need is just converting the output value (string separated by "|") to an array, then you can do it just by

```
Local $arr = StringSplit($var, "|")
```

Comment: If you just want to cycle through each returned file entry, you just need to add the third parameter to the StringSplit function and then you can use the For-...-In-...-loop. `$files = StringSplit($var, "|", 2)` and then `For $file In $files`. Inside this loop you can just use `$file` to use each individual entry...